# MYSQL order NULL between two particular records

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is there a way to set the default order used by MYSQL to be NULL in a specific record.

my table:

```
id     state
1       downloading
2       NULL
3       error
4       finish
5       downloading
6       NULL
7       NULL
8       fail
9       finish
10      error
```

I want NULL to be between 'downloading' and 'error' and not show 'finish', 'fail'.
(after query in MYSQL) I want result to be like this:

```
id     state
1       downloading
5       downloading
2       NULL
6       NULL
7       NULL
3       error
10       error
```

my query:(not working)

```
SELECT * FROM `report_table` 
WHERE
    state NOT IN ('finish','fail')
ORDER BY
    case 
       when state= 'downloading' then 1 
       when state IS NULL then 2
       when state= 'error' then 3
       else 6
    end, state ASC , id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY id ASC` ?

Comment: @Heru-Luin: That doesen't help. the results are already ordered by ID ASC.

Comment: You could use mysql's [`FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field)  -> `ORDER BY FIELD(\`state\`,'downloading',NULL,'error','fail','finish')`

Comment: Few questions: why are ids changing in the "after" view of your data? I.e. Why `downloading` id changed from 5 in "before" to "2" in after? Second, what is the rule for where NULL should be? Why not between `error` and `fail` for example? It would help if you add your SELECT for clarity of your question

Comment: There are bigger problems here. See @G.Stoynev's comment!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as you can assign custom ordering for the cases you want and the rest will be ordered by default.

```
order by 
        case 
           when state= 'downloading' then 1 
           when state IS NULL then 2
           when state= 'error' then 3
           when state= 'fail' then 4
           when state= 'finish' then 5
           else 6
        end
```

Comment: im using this :

order by 
        case 
           when state= 'downloading' then 1 
           when state IS NULL then 2
           when state= 'error' then 3
           when state= 'fail' then 4
           when state= 'finish' then 5
           else 6
        end, state ASC , savesize DESC, try ASC

it's true?

Answer (score 1):

Generally SQL allows you to ORDER BY any expression you want. That is not a necessity to provide only column names. So you may design expression which will order your data as you wish. Let's say we choose magic value "dzzzzz" which stays between "download" and "error". And then just write

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(state, "dzzzz").
```

But be careful - MySQL is not really efficient in such things.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
ORDER BY 
    FIELD(IFNULL(state, 'null'), 'downloading', 'null', 'error', 'fail', 'finish');
```

In this case we use the `FIELD` function - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` expression in `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT id, state
FROM mytable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN state = 'downloading' THEN 'aa'
              WHEN state IS NULL THEN 'ab'
              ELSE state
         END, id
```

This way `'downloading'` records will be first, followed by `NULL` records, followed by the rest of the records.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1176e/2)

Comment: @AdminFile3 What's your problem?